# Animate jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I do have a small issue with my jQuery Code

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AnimateCloud() {
        $("#cloudAmu").animate({
            "left": "+150%"
        }, 5000, 'linear');
        return false;
    }

    function AnimateCloud2() {
        $("#cloudAmu").animate({
            "right": "+150%"
        }, 5000, 'linear');
        return false;
    }

    $(document).ready(
        AnimateCloud().then(AnimateCloud2())
    );
</script>
```

Do you have any idea what is the problem?

Best regards

Goldiman

Comment: `Boolean` does not have method `.then()`

Comment: Thank everybody, for you help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because your functions are returning a boolean value of `false`, which does not have a `then()` method.

To chain the calls to your functions you need to return the `promise` from the calls you make to `animate()`. Try this:

```
function AnimateCloud() {
    return $("#cloudAmu").animate({
        "left": "+150%"
    }, 5000, 'linear').promise();
}

function AnimateCloud2() {
    return $("#cloudAmu").animate({
        "right": "+150%"
    }, 5000, 'linear').promise();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    AnimateCloud().then(AnimateCloud2)
});
```

Note that it appears that both `AnimateCloud()` and `AnimateCloud2()` contain the same logic and could be improved.

Comment: `$(document).ready(AnimateCloud().then(AnimateCloud2));` won't work as required. It is better to wrap it with `function() { }`: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3uL8rbjp/).

Comment: You're right, my bad. I thought you meant add an anon. function to the `then()` call, I didn't see that `ready()` was missing one,

Comment: I will leave comment with fiddle as an example.

Answer (score 1):

you try to call a then() function but AnimateCloud() return false.

```
function AnimateCloud(complete) {
    $("#cloudAmu").animate({
        "left": "+150%"
    }, 5000, 'linear', complete);
}

AnimateCloud(function() {
    AnimateCloud2()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call function on `AnimateCloud()` which is not a jQuery object.
You can call `AnimateCloud2()` from inside `AnimateCloud()` when it completes its animation, see below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AnimateCloud() {
        $("#cloudAmu").animate({
            "left": "+150%"
        }, 5000, 'linear', function(){
          AnimateCloud2();
       });

        return false;
    }

    function AnimateCloud2() {
        $("#cloudAmu").animate({
            "right": "+150%"
        }, 5000, 'linear');
        return false;
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        AnimateCloud();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Regent, I have updated my answer. It should be calling after finishing animation.

Comment: One more thing to do: it has to be either `$(document).ready(AnimateCloud);` or `$(document).ready(function() {  AnimateCloud(); });` [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3uL8rbjp/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Cause animate method in jquery not execute till the previous animate finished.. you can just use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         AnimateCloud();
        AnimateCloud2();
});
```